# Allow Customer Community Plus user to see other contacts where they are all Related Contacts to the same account

Tags: community, sharing, sharing-sets

Background:

- Contacts to Multiple Accounts is enabled
- Contact External OWD is set to Private
- Community users are using the Customer Community Plus license

Scenario:

- There is *Account A*
- *Contact A* has an indirect relationship to *Account A* (via AccountContactRelation)
- *Contact B* has an indirect relationship to *Account A* (via AccountContactRelation)

*(Ie Account A is NOT the direct account for either contact)*

If *Contact A* logs into the community, they should be able to see:

1. The *Account A* record
2. See *Contact B* listed under Related Contacts

I have 1 working using a sharing set that specifies for the Account object --> User:Contact.RelatedAccount = Contact:Account

For 2, I want something like Contact object --> User:Contact.RelatedAccount = Contact.RelatedAccount (ie share Contact records where the contacts both have a AccountContactRelation with the same account). But I don't think this is possible with sharing sets.

Is this possible? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Sharing rules, yes. At scale, this is going to get ugly. The alternative is to implement access control (incl. "data security") in your own services (e.g. custom REST API, custom LWC, ...) and route all requests through your services.

Comment: Thanks. Re sharing rules, what does the rule look like? Since we can only share with groups, roles, etc. As opposed to the more explicit style that sharing sets offer.